# Finding specific Raspberry Pis on one network?

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm teaching a class on the Raspberry Pi so I will have a bunch of Pis connected to a single access point. I'm trying to figure out how I can make sure the student is SSHing into the correct Pi.

My Ideas:

- Mac Address

  - I'm under the impression that the mac address isn't printed on the Rpi3 or the box is comes with so I couldn't use that to identify it.
- Change the hostname

  - This would work because I could use `ssh pi@<hostname>.local` but it seems you can't change this with the config text. You can only change the hostname once you're SSH'd into the Pi.
- SSH over USB

  - This should work without issue however I feel like it would be over complicating things for people who have never used linux / RPi before.
- Reboot Pis

  - Very slow and dumb idea but I could just have people watch the power indicators of the Pi and I can SSH them one by one turning them off.

**How can I an easily way to identify a user's Rpi on network with many Pis?**

Comment: Can't you change the hostnames in advance?

Comment: Second question: Can you log into the access point to get the IP addresses assigned to the Pis?

Comment: @Brick Not sure what you mean by `in advance` but I'm under the impression you have to be connected to the Pi in order to change the hostname. I have full access to the router

Comment: I meant you set up the Pis before the students arrive, doing each Pi one at a time.

Comment: Nope, they are bringing their own hardware

Comment: I teach a class using the Pi and I made a base SD card image with all the software needed pre-installed and use a script to change the hostname and SSH certificates. This all happens before the students check out the Pi from the library when the Pi comes back I wipe and rewrite the card. I also move the network (wpa_supplicant) config to the boot partition so that they can modify the wifi setup from any computer.

Comment: MAC address is just one command away with `ifconfig`, or `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address` (for wlan0 `cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address`), you can then write down all the MAC addresses for each Pi, and assign each Pi with an unique IP based on Mac address at your router. This is probably the best approach in this situation, because a) you have the full control of all the IPs and data; b) there is no reconfiguration required at home when the students bring their Pi home on another network.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you said, I suggest this:

- Log into the router.
- Have the students connect their Pis one at a time.
- As each Pi is connected, note the IP address assigned to it.
- Have the students log into their Pi by IP address the first time.
- First lesson is how to change the hostname!